# Split Pandas DataFrame with DatetimeIndex by na or missing rows into blocks

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I hava a Pandas DataFrame with a DatetimeIndex and want to split it into blocks of continously connected rows removing the nan rows.

```
                           Temperature  Humidity
2020-01-01 00:00:00+00:00  20           40 
2020-01-01 00:01:00+00:00  21           40
2020-01-01 00:02:00+00:00  NaN          NaN
2020-01-01 00:03:00+00:00  22           41
2020-01-01 00:04:00+00:00  NaN          NaN
2020-01-01 00:05:00+00:00  NaN          NaN
2020-01-01 00:06:00+00:00  NaN          NaN
2020-01-01 00:07:00+00:00  21           41
2020-01-01 00:08:00+00:00  21           41
2020-01-01 00:09:00+00:00  21           42
```

Result should be a list of the following three DataFrames:

```
                           Temperature  Humidity
2020-01-01 00:00:00+00:00  20           40 
2020-01-01 00:01:00+00:00  21           40

                           Temperature  Humidity
2020-01-01 00:03:00+00:00  22           41

                           Temperature  Humidity
2020-01-01 00:07:00+00:00  21           41
2020-01-01 00:08:00+00:00  21           41
2020-01-01 00:09:00+00:00  21           42
```

Any help?

Comment: do you need to check for both Temperature and Humidity be `NaN` or do you need to check for either ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us try use `cumsum` with `isnull` create the `groupby` key

```
d = {x : y for x , y in df.dropna().groupby(df.isnull().cumsum().sum(1))}
d[0]
                          Temperature  Humidity
2020-01-0100:00:00+00:00         20.0      40.0
2020-01-0100:01:00+00:00         21.0      40.0
```

Answer (score 3):

Let's try using `cumsum` to identify the blocks:

```
na = df.Temperature.isna().cumsum()

for i,d in df.loc[na.eq(0) | na.duplicated()].groupby(na):
    print(d)
```

Output:

```
                           Temperature  Humidity
2020-01-01 00:00:00+00:00         20.0      40.0
2020-01-01 00:01:00+00:00         21.0      40.0
                           Temperature  Humidity
2020-01-01 00:03:00+00:00         22.0      41.0
                           Temperature  Humidity
2020-01-01 00:07:00+00:00         21.0      41.0
2020-01-01 00:08:00+00:00         21.0      41.0
2020-01-01 00:09:00+00:00         21.0      42.0
```